# Overriding CSS properties for iframe width

Tags: html, css, iframe, overriding

I'm trying to put an iframe into a webpage, but no matter what I try to put in either the iframe properties or the custom CSS section of the website builder (or how many times I try to add !important to anything from width to right-margin), I can't get the iframe to extend rightward further than the page's preset width.

Here's an example of the page and iframe that I'm working with: (Edit: no longer available)

I need that script/iframe to be wide enough to show the search area.  It seems pointless to copy and paste code and attributes I've tried setting, because nothing I do seems to have any effect, but just for showing how much I have no idea what I'm doing, here's my iframe code:

```
<iframe id="idxFrame"  style="padding:0; margin:0; padding-top: 0px; overflow-x:auto;
width:1000px!important; border:0px solid transparent; background-color:transparent;
max-width:none!important; right-margin:-200px!important" frameborder="0" 
scrolling="on" src="http://www.themls.com/IDXNET/Default.aspx?wid=8MSsp7Pf9eI55yjkDuB%2blX5awn7LnnVXh5PNYhq2ImAEQL" 
width="1200px" height="900px">
</iframe>
```

The "Website Builder" that I'm forced to use to make these kinds of pages is infuriating, but it does have a "Custom CSS" area where I can input additional CSS information.  Is there something I could generically use to set iframes to their own widths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is being cut off is because there are some parent containers in the page structure that have the attribute `overflow: hidden;` to ensure content that is too wide doesn't break the layout.

I don't know how your system works but you could try adding the following code to your Custom CSS area:

```
.LayoutContainer {
    overflow: visible !important;
}

.LayoutContainer div div {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Be aware that it will mess with your layout and spawn a horizontal scroll-bar on smaller screens.

---

**Update:**

The above CSS would affect your entire website. If you really want to go through with it, use the following CSS instead to make sure only this page is affected. The system generates a unique ID number for every page and we're taking advantage of that.

```
body#page_33219e82-0110-40bb-a172-3d05dc78f406 .LayoutContainer {
    overflow: visible !important;
}

body#page_33219e82-0110-40bb-a172-3d05dc78f406 .LayoutContainer div div {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that your are using `right-margin` when you should be using `margin-right`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I modified to get it to work and here is a screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/R2VeIAnNJVd

```
.LayoutContainer { overflow: visible; }
.LayoutContainer div div { overflow: visible !important; }
```

As stated above and as seen in the screenshot, you can see that the iframe extends out past your content wrapper.